# AJAX - run two requests at same time, but one of them repeatedly with some interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred, deferred

I want to implement following functionality:
There's first AJAX request which launches data import to MS SQL database. There's a table in database containing some data about the import (total records, proceeded records, start time etc.). This data in table is constantly updated during the import.

Second AJAX request should get updated data from the table every 5 seconds, for example, and display it on the page in form of some notification.

The issue I'm facing is following: first request starts, it takes some minutes to execute it. In meantime second request is called with 5 seconds interval, but all the requests are not executed until first one is done, they are all queued and have status "Pending". I can't figure out what the matter is. Looks like I'm not able to start second AJAX request during first one's TTFB.

I have also tried to use jQuery.when() and jQuery.then() but I don't understand how to make an AJAX call with interval inside jQuery.when(). Is there any way to achieve the functionality that I'm aiming to?

Here is my code, RunImport function is called on import button click:

```
var resultCheck, resultRun, intervalId = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        CheckActiveImports();
        
    });
    
    function CheckActiveImports() {
        var jqXHR = $.ajax({
            url: "exhaust.aspx/GetRunningImports",
            async:true,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#output').html("Checking for running imports...");
            },
            success: OnCheckSuccess,
            failure: function (result) {
                resultCheck = "Failure: " + result.responseText;
            },
            error: function (result) {
                resultCheck = "Error: " + result.responseText;
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('#output').html(resultCheck);
            }
        });
        return jqXHR;
    }

    function OnCheckSuccess(result)
    {
        var data = result.d; //JSON.parse(result).d;
        if (data.length) {
            var res = "";
            for (var x in data) {
                var format = 'Job running: ' + data[x].JobType + '. ' + data[x].Counter + ' of ' + data[x].Total + ' records processed<br /> \
                              Speed: ' + data[x].Speed + ' records per minute. \
                              Estimated time of completion: ' + data[x].EstTime + '.';
                res += format;
            }
            resultCheck = res;
        }
        else {
            resultCheck = 'Currently there are no jobs running.';
        }
    }

    function RunImport()
    {
        intervalId = window.setInterval(CheckActiveImports, 5000);
        RunImportAjax();
    }

    function RunImportDeferred() {
        
        var RunImportXHR = RunImportAjax(),
            CheckImportXHR = CheckActiveImports();
        $.when(RunImportXHR, CheckImportXHR).then(function () {
            $('#output').html(resultCheck);
            $('#output2').html(resultRun);
        });
    }

    function RunImportAjax() {
        var jqXHR = $.ajax({
            url: "exhaust.aspx/RunImport",
            async:true,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#output2').html("Running import...");
            },
            success: function (result) {
                window.clearInterval(intervalId);
                var data = result.d;
                if (data.length) {
                    var res = "";
                    for (var x in data) {
                        var format = 'Job finished: ' + data[x].JobType + '. ' + data[x].Counter + ' records processed.<br />';
                        res += format;
                    }
                    resultRun = res;

                }
            },
            failure: function (result) {
                resultRun = "Failure: " + result.responseText;
            },
            error: function (result) {
                resultRun = "Error: " + result.responseText;
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('#output2').html(resultRun);
            }
        });
        return jqXHR;
  }
```

Comment: The main thing I was doing wrong was calling two ASPX page (static) webmethods. I have moved the method for getting data from MSSQL table to ASMX webservice and everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a "disposer pattern", in which a "resource" (a `window.setInterval()`) is established when an import is initiated, and disposed of when the import's promise settles.

The need for outer vars disappears as does the need for `RunImportDeferred()`. `RunImportAjax()` can be renamed `RunImport()` or similar. `CheckActiveImports()` and `OnCheckSuccess()` can stay as they are.

```
function RunImport() {
    $('#output2').html("Running import...");
    var intervalId = window.setInterval(CheckActiveImports, 5000); // establish a progress observer
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'exhaust.aspx/RunImport',
        async:true,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).then(function (result) {
        var data = result.d,
            res;
        if (data.length) {
            res = jQuery.map(data, function(item) {
                return 'Job finished: ' + item.JobType + '. ' + item.Counter + ' records processed.';
            }).join('<br />');
        } else {
            res = '';
        }
        $('#output2').html(res);
        return result; // in case RunImport's caller is interested.
    }, function(error) {
        $('#output2').html(error.message);
    }).always(function() {
        window.clearInterval(intervalId); // dispose of the progress observer
    });
}
```

Providing the server has the capacity to service the import and the progress requests, then this should work.

The progress observer could be better written, not to involve `window.setInterval()` but that's probably a separate issue.

---

**Edit: Periodic observer without setInterval()**

A periodic observer without `setInterval()` is reasonably simple and stopping it can be better than the original `clearInterval()`, by also (optionally) aborting any pending ajax.

In the approach below, :

- The detailed behaviour of `CheckActiveImports()` (and `OnCheckSuccess()`) is controlled by passing several parameters.
- `CheckActiveImports()` returns a stopper function which is used as a disposer in `RunImport()`.

In the caller, you can call the returned disposer function as follows :

- `dispose()`: stop further ajax calls being made.
- `dispose(true)`: abort the pending ajax call and stop further ajax calls being made.

You probably want the latter.

```
function CheckActiveImports($container, interval, initMessage, finalMessage) {
    $container.html(initMessage || '');
    var jqXHR = null,
        timeoutRef = setTimeout(check, interval),
        _recurse_ = true;
    function check() {
        jqXHR = $.ajax({
            url: "exhaust.aspx/GetRunningImports",
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnCheckSuccess.bind(null, $container),
            error: function (result) {
                $container.text("Error: " + result.responseText);
            },
            complete: function() {
                if(_recurse_) {
                    timeoutRef = setTimeout(check, interval); // recursive call
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return function(abort) {
        if(abort && jqXHR) jqXHR.abort();
        clearTimeout(timeoutRef);
        _recurse_ = false;
        $container.text(finalMessage || '');
    };
}

function OnCheckSuccess($container, result) {
    var data = result.d, //JSON.parse(result).d
        res;
    if(data.length) {
        res = jQuery.map(data, function(item) {
            return 'Job running: ' + item.JobType + '. ' + item.Counter + ' of ' + item.Total + ' records processed<br /> \
                Speed: ' + item.Speed + ' records per minute. \
                Estimated time of completion: ' + item.EstTime + '.';
        }).join('<br/>');
    } else {
        res = 'Currently there are no jobs running.';
    }
    $container.text(res);
}

function RunImport() {
    var $container = $('#output2').html("Running import...");
    var dispose = CheckActiveImports($('#output'), 5000, 'Checking for running imports...', ''); // start the progress observer
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'exhaust.aspx/RunImport',
        async:true,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).then(function (result) {
        var data = result.d,
            res;
        if (data.length) {
            res = jQuery.map(data, function(item) {
                return 'Job finished: ' + item.JobType + '. ' + item.Counter + ' records processed.';
            }).join('<br />');
        } else {
            res = '';
        }
        $container.html(res);
        return result; // in case RunImport's caller is interested.
    }, function(error) {
        $container.html(error.message);
    }).always(function() {
        dispose(true); // dispose of the progress observer and abort any pending ajax.
    });
}
```

Comment: Your code is superb, thanks a lot! I am not a fan of window.setInterval() as well, could you please give a hint on better implementation of progress observer (or some link where it's described)?

Comment: Wow, I thought I knew JavaScript and AJAX, but looks like I'm not even close to your level. Thanks for another great code snippet!

Comment: Unfortunately, even I make mistakes. I just made a couple of corrections.

Comment: It's OK, only those who do nothing don't make mistakes. I've moved _recurse_ to CheckActiveImports parameters anyway to be able to call it on document.ready without repeating.